# How to get the profile of a lead/object owner within a flow?

Tags: flow

While within a flow, I need to get the Profile of the owner.

I can do it with 2 queries, Is there a smart/soql or other way to get it? and reduce the API calls ?

something more efficient than doing 2 record queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use a formula, such as ***Lead.Owner.Profile.Name***?   The formula in flows is actually pretty robust, but tedious to work with.  I've used the formula functionality to do lookups in FOR LOOPS to avoid extra queries in my flow.

Answer (score 1):

You said you can do it with 2 queries, so you can reduce the number of queries to one single nested query (assuming you are using the result of the first query to do the second one).

[See this reference](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/).

Notice that you can use only one nested query. If you try to use a third query inside the second one, Salesforce will give you an error.

Comment: Point is that there are no SOQL queries in flows.  It's all point and click.